# variable in variable in php

Tags: php

```
$var="profile['Gamer']['last_name']";
echo ${$var};
```

Gives

> Undefined variable: profile['Gamer']['last_name']

. But if i try to echo $profile['Gamer']['last_name'] value exist

I have tried echo $$var that too didn't work

Comment: Specifying an array index using curly braces isn't possible.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What's wrong with `echo $profile['Gamer']['last_name'];`

Comment: Only `${"profile"}['Gamer']['last_name']` will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$var="profile['Gamer']['last_name']";
eval('$result = $' . $var . ';');
echo $result;
```

Keep in mind that there are serious security issues to something like this, and that your code will probably be very hard to understand for anybody but your self.

Comment: my aim is to check if user has filled in data for a database field. If filled i assign him some points. To do so in another table i store the fild name and the points associated with it. so what's the best way to implement. and what r the security issues . None one but i have acess to thsi table

Answer (score 4):

There is no variable `profile['Gamer']['last_name']`. There is only a variable named `profile`.

```
$var = "profile";
echo ${$var}['Gamer']['last_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$var="profile['Gamer']['last_name']";
eval("echo $".$var.";");
```